# I get a SQL Server Program type out of range (0) (SQLGetData) error when connecting to SQL Server through Python using the FreeTDS driver

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, freetds

Am using MSSQL database server. I connected with SQL using pyodbc. I tried to get value from database.Am getting error while fetching the value from database.I mentioned the detail of connecting database below

```
 Area_code=1
 cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER=x.y.z.a;PORT=1433;DATABASE=xxxx;UID=yyyy;PWD=zzzz;TDS_Version=8.0;')
 cursor = cnxn.cursor()
 cursor.execute("exec MOB_GetBranch @AreaID='%s',@CompanyID='419',@lang='en_US'"%Area_code)
 result = cursor.fetchall()
```

I can't able to get value from database. am getting the error like

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   result = cursor.fetchall()
   pyodbc.Error: ('HY003', '[HY003] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Program type out of range (0) (SQLGetData)')
```

Comment: The (short) discussion thread [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyodbc/mQA49sZK8Vk) may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have wrong conn. strings or you do not have appropriate driver for this db.

Comment: i can able to connect with SQL but i can't able to get value from the database.So the connection is right.

Comment: @saro as I said, I need more information. I tried to guess - it did not worked.